# Need to load div on viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I built a animated percentage bar in css and I want to delay the load of the animation until the viewport reaches the container div. I have tried every lazyload jquery script I can find on google and still can't get one to do what I need. The content I need to lazy load is inside the column div

```
<section class="parallax-container2">
<img class="responsive-img parallax2" src="images/image2.jpg">
<div class="container">
<div class="row fadeInParagraph">
<div class="col s12 m6 l6 index">
<div class="progresscss"><div id="progressbar"><span class="text">89%
</span><div id="progress" ></div></div><div class="line"></div></div>
<div class="progresscss1"><div id="progressbar1"><span class="text">74%
</span><div id="progress1" ></div></div><div class="line"></div></div>
<div class="progresscss2"><div id="progressbar2"><span class="text">61%
</span><div id="progress2" ></div></div><div class="line"></div></div>
<div class="progresscss3"><div id="progressbar3"><span class="text">85%
</span><div id="progress3" ></div></div><div class="line"></div></div>
</div></div></section>
```

Comment: Looking at the className.. I hope i am safe to assume that you are doing some parallax magic. Have you already created a global scroll event listener that you can work with ?

Comment: I was doing a little parallax but ended up getting issues with it as well since it was fighting with my header parallax which is a higher priority. I'm setting the global scroll event today to see if I can get that to do what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method to check if your element is in view port, 
Also you need to fire it on scroll event, may be using setTimout so that it doesn't fires too many times.

```
isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
```

Comment: Any chance you could dumb that down a hair? My css/html skills I have figured out, java not so much.

Comment: So to me seems like you are using materialize for creating parallax.You need to fire parallax only when your div is in view port for that you can keep on checking weather your div is in viewport on scroll events. So basically you need to fire $('.parallax2').parallax(); event when isScrolledIntoView method returns true.

Comment: I use materialize for the grid. The parallax effect I'm working with isn't theirs. However, that makes sense and I'll give it a try. Thank you!